# How do you call an exe from code and get around possible UAC action against this?

Tags: c#, process, uac, windows-installer

I'm using system.diagnostics.process to start an msi file in quiet mode. I'm getting an exit code 1625, and I suspect its because UAC is preventing it from running. I've turned off the UAC prompts but no dice...

How can I make sure that I'm properly elevating the privileges of the msiexec so it actually runs?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UAC Elevation in Managed Code: Starting Elevated Processes](http://chrison.net/UACElevationInManagedCodeStartingElevatedProcesses.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I did. You'll get the accepted answer since it's the more general solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = "/i " +  "\""+Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\"+msiPath +"\"" +" /q";
startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";


Process installProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Well, this is what I did, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your process with the admin privileges and see if the problem persists

Comment: It was running as my account, which had administrative privileges.  I didn't 'elevate' the msiexec.exe to have high enough UAC permissions when I called it from code.